# 16GB memory card, ive used 2GB and yet have 14GB of free space, how can i use that 14GB and why is it saying low of space on sd card???

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory, huawei

im using my 16gb memory card as to store all my apps on etc.. as my internal memory is too full so i chamged my sd card to default storage, but now as i have been using it it says storage space is getting low... but when i check it i therefore have 14gb left in total space i can use but it wont let me ... that's heaps of space I can use, I've tried moving apparently from sd to phone but internal is too full so I can't... I don't see how I need to do that anyway as I've only used up 2gb on sd and yet have 14gb I can use but why is it saying low on storage space on my sd? And how can I go by using the other 14gb ?

Comment: I assume your device (name?) is rooted? How did you make your SDCard the "default storage"? I know it's possible on some devices to switch internal/external SDCard addressing, but I've never heard someone switching device-internal storage to SD.

Answer (score 1):

This may be expected, depending on what phone you are using.  The original standard of SD card readers had a 2GB limit on them.  These readers could read cards that had more space, but only had enough memory registers to read the first 2GB of them.  Sometimes a firmware update can increase this from 2GB to 4GB, but it's extremely rare.

From the [wikipedia article on the SD standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital):

```
Capacity
SDSC (SD): 1 MB to 2 GB,
   some 4 GB available.
SDHC: >2 GBs to 32 GB
SDXC: >32 GB to 2 TB,
   some 32 GB available.
```

Comment: So there is no way I can change it?

Comment: You mean, there are really Android devices out there being bound to some standard *that old*? SDHC was released 2006, according to the linked Wikipedia page. The first Android devices came 2008. I doubt even the very first ones came without SDHC.

Comment: This is why I said "may be expected".  Depends on the device and whatever settings are anywhere else.  There isn't any information on what device is being used, but it's the only thing I can think of that would limit a card to 2GB.  It may even be a software issue that is locking the phone to the old SD standard instead of SDHC, which a firmware/software update can fix.